# How can I get all Recurring PayIn Registrations with Mangopay api

Tags: recurring-billing, mangopay

According to the documentation I can get one recurring PayIn registration with this call to the api of mangopay `GET .../v2.01/ClientId/recurringpayinregistrations/RecurringPayinRegistrationId`
https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2.01/payins#e1052_the-recurring-payin-object

Do I have to save `RecurringPayinRegistrationId` in my database to retreive them all myself or does Mangopay store them in their database?